# Получение из функции ссылки на объект

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Добрый день товарищи!

Продолжаю писать свою **CMS** систему, имеется функция, которая выполняет подключение к базе данных и возвращает ссылку на объект PDO, то есть активное соединение с базой:

```
function &index_databases_mysql() {
    $dh                     =   'localhost';
    $dl                     =   'root';
    $dp                     =   '12345';
    $dn                     =   'dbname';
    #
    static $database_link       =   false;
    #
    if (!$database_link) {
        try {
            $database_link      =   new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dn.';host='.$dh, $dl, $dp, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
        } catch (PDOException $ie) {
            define('INDEX_DATABASES_MYSQL_CONNECTED', '1');
        }
        #
        if ($database_link) {
            $database_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
            #
            define('INDEX_DATABASES_MYSQL_CONNECTED', '2');
        }
    }
    #
    return $database_link;
}
```

Я плохо знаю классы и ссылки, но задача следующая :

1. Переменные не должны получать копию объекта, они должны получить лишь ссылку на него и работать с одним и тем же объектом для подключения к базе.
2. Подключение должно быть выполнено всего 1 раз, в остальных случаях оно попросту не выполняется, а уже возвращается ссылка на него.

**`$da = &index_databases_mysql();//получить доступ к базе`**

и так ещё 2 - 3 переменных в ходе работы сценария получат ссылки на одно и то же подключение.

Правильно ли выполнена поставленная задача?

Comment: function &index_databases_mysql() {...}

В PHP5 функции уже возвращают ссылку на объект, поэтому можно просто:

    function index_databases_mysql() {...}

Кроме того, Ваш вариант в PHP5.4 вызовет STRICT ERROR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В php5 нет копирования объекта при создании на него ссылки. Для копирования, есть специальное ключевое слово [clone](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php)

**Перенесено из комментария.**

Я бы сделал по другому. 
Вы слышали про объект singleton?
Если нет, то в кратце это объект, который существует в единственном экземпляпе.

---

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
 * User: dimka3210
 * Date: 02.03.13
 * Time: 15:12
 */
class DB
{
private static $instance = null;

public static function getInstance()
{
    if (self::$instance == null) {
        self::$instance = new DB();
    }

    return self::$instance;

}

private function __construct(){
    // Connection code!
}

}
```

Comment: Тоесть всё сделано верно?

Comment: Я бы сделал по другому. 
Вы слышали про объект singleton?
Если нет, то в кратце это объект, который существует в единственном экземпляпе.

----

<?php
/**
 * Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
 * User: dimka3210
 * Date: 02.03.13
 * Time: 15:12
 */
class DB
{
 private static $instance = null;

 public static function getInstance()
 {
  if (self::$instance == null) {
   self::$instance = new DB();
  }

  return self::$instance;

 }
 
 private function __construct(){
  // Connection code!
 }

}

Comment: Теперь обращаемся $connect = DB::getInstance();

И в коннекте объект подключения.